# Getting an event when user press back key for dismissing a softinput Keyboard in android

Tags: android

I want the event name which is called when user presses the back key to hide the keyboard and how we call the same. Because onKeyDown method for back press is only worked when keyboard is hidden.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634346/keyboard-hide-event

Answer (score 0):

you can not get if virtual keyboard has been displayed or not directly. There is a workaround for this, in which we need to get window's available width, and Height and compare it with width and height values stored previously.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the soft keyboard is present, it is actually dismissed when back is pressed because when it shows up, it actually has focus. It has focus because its ideally being used by the user and needs focus.