# Capture hide keyboard button event Android 4

Tags: android, show-hide, android-softkeyboard, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've been some days looking for a way to catch "Hide softkey onscreen button" event.

The thing is I have an activity with windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" because if not, when softKeyboard appears, layouts are rescaled and I need them to keep their original size. As I have a login form, I have catch several events, and I scroll parent layout manually.

But the problem is that It seems there is no way to catch hide softkey onscreen button event, and when this happens, I can't revert the scroll and things have more than enough bottom margin.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to intercept the event of hiding the softKeyboard I assume when the user presses the Back key.

If so, you are able to intercept the press of Back Key **before** it is passed to the IME using `public boolean onKeyPreIme (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`. 
In that way you are able to execute code just before the hiding occurs.

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyPreIme%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Also read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634346/keyboard-hide-event) answers I have found

Hope this helps!