# KeyBoard Hidden Event

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have read many threads, but I was not very clear. How to capture the closing of the keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

you can do the following to detect if the hardware key board is shown/hidden

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 

// if a hardware keyboard is available
if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

you can do the following **Work around** to detect if the virtual key board is shown/hidden

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
final int actualHeight = getHeight();

if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
    // Keyboard is shown
} else {
    // Keyboard is hidden
}

super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
 }
```

To see how to implement , check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423586/864955

Comment: Because is not a hardware keyboard, but it is the soft keyboard

Comment: I have added the Work around to detect if the virtual key board / soft keyboard  is shown/hidden. Have you tried that?

Comment: In what way? I also added android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard" in the manifest.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show how to implement it. It links to another answer. please let me know if it works

Comment: The solution in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown