# How to override back button press when virtual keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, android-button, android-virtual-keyboard

In my app when the virtual keyboard appears it is pushes up my menu from the bottom, and it is not so nice and it is also cover some of the content so i just hide it when the virtual keyboards shows up.

But when i press back to hide the keyboard, i want to show my menu again, but nothing happens, except the virtual keyboard disappears like default.

I tried:

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() 
        {
            LinearLayout menuLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
            menuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

also tried WITHOUT:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

None of them worked.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

You should not override `onBackPressed` method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android) how to resolve your problem

Comment: "You should not override onBackPressed method" -> this is not true...
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-webviews
In many aspects your right, but not in general..