# EditText in a listview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView wich contains EditText views. When touching these EditText views, the soft key pad comes up (as desired).

When using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" the touch pad hides the bottom part of the ListView and thus possibly the EditText view in focus (just touched). I know that this can be solved by using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">. However, in this case due to resizing the EditText view loses focus.

I am now wondering whether it would be possible to both have the key pad not hide the EditText view and also have it not lose focus.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Try this code

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setClickable(true);
editText.requestFocus();
```

of course the first three lines can be placed in xml layout with

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

Then simply call editText.requestFoxus(); right after the key pad comes into view

Comment: i checked doing that also.I called editText.requestFocus() on focus change listener i.e when key pad opens but for no result.Is there any special event when keypad opens??/

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android

Comment: I SOLVED THE ISSUE BY GENERATING A DYNAMIC LIST VIEW USING LINEAR LAYOUTS.