# Detecting soft-keyboard State

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to detect the state of the softkeyboard using the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` i have found multiple solutions where either `adjustPan` or `adjustResize` is required any Help on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "state of the soft keyboard"?

Comment: I want to detect the opening or closing of the softkeyboard...thats what i meant by state

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16102728/1207921) is the best you can do. Android is sorely lacking APIs for interacting with the soft keyboard at the UI level, beyond just telling it to show or hide.

Comment: I have used this ..but this resizes my layout..

Comment: looking for something better

Comment: You can detect the opening or closing by getting the keyboard shown/hidden status,

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    
        if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
            writeToLog("Software Keyboard was shown");
        } else {
            writeToLog("Software Keyboard was not shown");
        }

Comment: You might be able to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265). I suggest using the "new answer" - It works quite well (at least with my tests it does)

Comment: Ankush the answer you suggested requires adjustResize or adjustPan i need something with adjustNothing

Comment: Prokash Sarkar....this solution might not be feasable in my case will try and let you know