# Android switching focus makes keyboard disappear

Tags: android, android-view

I want to switch between two `EditText` views when `KEYCODE_DEL` button is pressed.

My code works, it indeed focuses previous `EditText`, but when it does that, the keyboard vanishes, and cursor is located before the actual text in that `EditText`.

To make it more vivid, when the focus switches, the `EditText` looks like this:

`|23` where `|` is the cursor position and keyboard is hidden.

Here is my code:

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        focusPreviousET();
        return true;
    }
else{
    super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    check();
    return true;
 }

private void focusPreviousET() {

    String sId = getId(getCurrentFocus());

    Identification id = new Identification(sId);

    etX = getETFromResource(id);

    if(isEmpty(etX)){
        etX.setEnabled(false);
        id.previousId();
        etX = getETFromResource(id);
        etX.requestFocus();
    }
}
public void check(){
       etX  = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
    if(etX.getText().toString().length()==2){
        focusNextFreeET();
    }
}
```

Also `check()` method doesn't work, and i don't know why... Method `focusNextFreeET()` works in other cases, but not here.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, cursor is actually located at the end when the `EditText` is filled with numbers like 22,31,10, and cursor is located at the beggining when the number has a 0 in front of it, like 01,02, etc... In both cases, keyboard is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these lines after focusing next item to open a keyboard

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: What is this "linearLayout"?

Comment: Okay, but is there some other way to do this, this way the keyboard hides, then un-hides. It looks really bad.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202895/maintain-keyboard-open-closed-state-for-edittext-when-app-comes-to-foreground) ,may be it helps