# Hide ImageView when keyboard appears, and show it when keyboard disappear

Tags: android, keyboard, android-imageview, android-edittext

How can i hide `ImageView` when keyboard appears (after pressing on some `EditText`).
And then show this `ImageView` when keyboard is dismissed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`OnFocusChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) might be the right thing for you.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // view/hide ImageView
    }
});
```

Comment: It works fine. But i faced another problem. By pressing Back button, to hide keyboard, `EditText` don't loose focus, so ImageViw is still Hiden. Is there some listener for dismissing keyboard?

Comment: @Procurares I'm glad you like it! Please upvote/accept the answer, if it helped you. Yep, that's possible. Read on that link to find out how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android

Answer (score 3):

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             // Hide your ImageView
               iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // (make the view gone)
    }else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Show your ImageView
              iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```