# How to make a notification/listener when the keyboard disappear on Android platform?

Tags: android, keyboard

My question is how to make a notification/listener when the keyboard disappear on Android platform. To be specific, it's a notification/listener **just after** keyboard disappear, like UIKeyboardDidHideNotification in iOS rather than UIKeyboardWillHideNotification

Before writing my question, i searched many many possible answers in Google and here, but they are neither what I'm looking for.It seems to be an piece of cake at the very beginning, however, I struggled whole week and got no good result.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate question. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android) out

Comment: @kushyar, onConfigurationChanged is only for non-soft keyboard. I got to know it possibly support soft keyboard, but actually not.