# Hide button view and then show it again

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to hide button at bottom of screen when soft keyboard is appear and then show it when keyboard will disappear. Looks like keyboard overflows button.

Comment: Look at this post, for the keyboard show/hidden events and play with your button visibility 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android

Comment: @Sid it doesn't work for soft keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This this code bit in your `AndroidManifest`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem, just learning android development

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration of your activity in manifest, you may add :

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then in your activity, add :

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        // Your keyboard is visible
        yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        // Your keyboard is hidden
        yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

More informations about Configuration change in [Handling the Configuration Change Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

More informations about Configuration class : [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)

Comment: It doesn't work for soft keyboard!

Comment: Did you also tried with KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES and KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO instead of HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES and HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO ?