# prevent only 1 view from coming up when keyboard is up

Tags: android, view, keyboard

there are 2 views which are set to "align parent bottom" as true in my activity. One is a textview and other one is a linear layout. I want to display this linear layout only when keyboard is up, that too on the top of keyboard. The issue is like when i tap on the edittext, keyboard is up with linear layout on top that.But the textview is also coming up. I dont want that textview to come up.I just want that linear layout to come up when keyboard shows. Is it possible?then how?

Comment: In order to achieve that you should make your own handler. So, when keyboard is up you decide which view/layout to be displayed, which to have its visibility changed, which to have its height increased/decreased. If you don't know how to make the handler, I suggest you try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android#7423586).