# Making part of layouts always visible when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `DialogFragment` with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_light">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/create_note_top_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#f2f3f5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Cancel"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Send"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/quote_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/edu4_create_note_quotes"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quote_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quote_image"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:text="The issue is that soft keyboard is very tricky and this\n quesakdf\njk\nlsd\nfj\nklsdjfklsdjfkl jsdklfj skldjkljfklsdjklfjsdklfjsdkljfkls"
            android:maxLines="5"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/quote_text"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_background_white"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/visibleTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Publish"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/switchPublishToCourse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want that when the keyboard is opened, the top panel (`android:id="@+id/create_note_top_panel"`) will be visible on top, and the dialog (it's background) will be above the keyboard, the bottom `TextView` and `ToggleButton` will be visible and the rest of the layout will be scrollable.

Comment: Maybe this SO answer will fit your needs. Howto capture the 'virtual keyboard show/hide' event in Android?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7423586/1027550

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how that helps me too much

Comment: I thought you were having difficulties listening to the event of the keyboard being opened.

Comment: No, I was having difficulties making certain parts of my dialog layout always visible when the keyboard is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: add `android:layout_weight="0" to the parts that you want to stay visible and`android:layout_weight="1" to the one that can be resized.
Here is the full xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_light">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/create_note_top_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#f2f3f5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Cancel"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Send"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/quote_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/edu4_create_note_quotes"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quote_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quote_image"
            android:text="The issue is that soft keyboard is very tricky and this\n quesakdf\njk\nlsd\nfj\nklsdjfklsdjfkl jsdklfj skldjkljfklsdjklfjsdklfjsdkljfkls\nend of tex"
            android:maxLines="5"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/create_note_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/quote_text"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_background_white"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/visibleTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Publish"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/switchPublishToCourse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the `Fragment` class:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}
```