# Android input method notification

Tags: android

I am trying to receive broadcast in my service whenever the keypad is visible on the screen.
Which broadcast action is triggered when input method appears and disappears on my screen.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you currently have code? If so, could you please provide a [mcve] in an [edit]?

Comment: I dont have any code yet but i am trying to make a service which log the keypad status.

Comment: Please look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android

Comment: I have gone through that blog but nowhere i found any relative answer. We see a keypad in notification bar whenever keypad pops up. So that is a service running somewhere in which receives the broadcast of keypad and starts the intent.

Comment: Well, obviously it isn't the "full solution" you want, but it tells you what code to use to notify the system when the keyboard becomes available or hides. It is up to you to implement the broadcast receiver and service and send the message. StackOverflow doesn't intend to be a tutorial service.

Comment: Thanks for your support