# Is there a method before onBackPressed()?

Tags: java, android

I mean when i open a keyboard i can hide it but this is not a method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    chatFragment.hideEmoticon();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

is there any method like "onhide"?

Comment: Please reference: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/how-to-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android`

Comment: You want to receive call back for before the soft keyboard does?

Comment: i try to implement https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3287 but now i see my idea is bad becouse when i call dismiss on EMoijSelecton this thing remove a globalRootVIew.. thanks for reply also

Comment: do you just want to hide the keyboard when the fragment is opened?