# KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK does not work on special button

Tags: android, keyboard

I need to intercept  hide keyboard  event. For this, I used *onKeyPreIme*  and *dispatchKeyEvent*. All good, when I push back button, I intercept this KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK. But there are problem devices like meizu. Where there is a special button "hide keyboard", which in turn is not caught in the callback.
Can you give advice, how I can achive this?

[screen with meizu keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urWDL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use method onMeasure() in your root view to detect if keyboard was shown or hidden
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135035

Comment: It doesn't work with  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". I used ViewTreeObserver