# Jetpack Compose Keyboard adjustment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-window

Is there a way where we can control for every screen different states of the keyboard, for example I have one screen where I want to adjust size of the keyboard to the screen and other screens where I do not want that. Currently I was using this
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` , but when other cases come along this is not working anymore, is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751925/how-to-set-windowsoftinputmode-programmatically-from-fragments
Basically, you can use `LocalContext.current` to get the current `Context`, cast to an activity and follow the answer above.