# Immersive mode while using keyboard

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In Xamarin.Forms app in `MainActivity.cs` I set immersive sticky mode:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        SetFullscreen();
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    void SetFullscreen()
    {
        var uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
        Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
        Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
    }
```

When a page with an `Entry` (input box) and the keyboard comes up, it goes out of immersive mode and all system bars become visible. When keyboard is hidden, all bars stay visible.

Also using `Acr.UserDialogs` with `ShowLoading()`.

How to stay in immersive mode all the time? Or how to return to immersive mode when closing the keyboard, and when calling `HideLoading()` of `UserDialogs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the `IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` interface.

Create a your listener:

```
class SystemUiVisibilityChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
    {
        public void OnSystemUiVisibilityChange([GeneratedEnum] StatusBarVisibility visibility)
        {
            if (visibility == StatusBarVisibility.Visible)
            {
                //your code here
            }
        }
    }
```

And attach it to your decor view:

```
View decorView = Window.DecorView;
decorView.SetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiVisibilityChangeListener());
var uiOptions = (int)decorView.SystemUiVisibility;
...
```

If this does not work you may have to explore listening for the keyboard to hide; here is some research to get you started [How to capture the "virtual keyboard show/hide" event in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/how-to-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android)

Comment: could you please share your solution, in case of other people get the problem too?!

Comment: I would also like to see how you solved this since I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I would also like to know. I've the same problem :(

Comment: Me too. Please!