# Android Navbar close keyboard button name

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have made a chat that looks as follows:

[image]

Then, when I click on the EditText, the keyboard opens and hides the `bottomNavigationView` by using:

```
    final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.et_Message);
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!isVisibleWhileSoftKeyboardShowing(editText) && hasFocus) {
                sView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //sView.smoothScrollBy(0, 5000);
                        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Then, when the user clicked on the arrow to close the keyboard:

I had liked it to show the `bottomNavigationView` again.

I tried to override `onBackPressed()` however it doesn't work since it seems like the arrow has a different name.

Any idea how to find when this arrow `IsClicked`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a chat project like you. I added this to activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in the manifest file. Now bottomNavigationView hide and show automatic as you wish.

Comment: It is not what I'm looking mate since I played a lot in order to try hiding it manually. I specifically look for the name of that down arrow button

Comment: I get it. If you can't find maybe you can look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365637/8956604). Good luck