# Listener on back pressed to close keyboard Android

Tags: android, keyboard, listener, observers, onbackpressed

[image]

Is there a way to set a listener on back pressed to close the keyboard ?

Answer (score -1):

override the function `onBackPressed()` from inside your `Activity`

Comment: already tried, method not called when I'm closing keyboard according logs

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/how-to-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android