# how to disable the collapsing of search view on back key pressed android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I have used Sherlock search view widget in action bar for search menu. The code snippet for initializing the search view

```
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    item.expandActionView();
    mSearchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setQuery(query, false);
    mSearchView.clearFocus();
```

The above code shows expanded search view with default search query. The problem is when I press back button the search view again collapses before returning to previous activity in android. I don't want the search view to collapse on back key press. How to prevent search view from collapsing on back key press?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629313/auto-collapse-actionbar-searchview-on-soft-keyboard-close

Comment: the above post is different from my problem. My search view get collapsed on back key press. I have to disable this default behavior. I don't want the search view to get collapsed ,it should be expanded always? any suggestion ?

Comment: did you get an answer for this ?

Answer (score 3):

`SearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)` should be enough if you have set the attribute `android:showAsAction="always"` in your menu xml.

The following snippet works for me:

**default_options.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/topbar_busqueda"
        androidshowAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**Activity**

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.default_options menu);
     MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
     prepareSearchViewAdapter(searchView, menuItem);
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
 }

private void prepareSearchViewAdapter(final SearchView searchView, MenuItem menuItem) {
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
}
```

Comment: Still works in 2020 with `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`.  My searchview was not in a menu, so I didn't need to set `showAsAction="always"`

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean value when search view is open like this

```
private Boolean isSearchPageIsOpen = true;
```

Then add the even to handle back button press

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(isSearchPageIsOpen ){

                do something here
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: search view back press does not call onKeydown Overriden method