# Auto Collapse ActionBar AutoCompleteTextView on Soft Keyboard close

Tags: android

I'm using `AutoCompleteTextView` (Not `SearchView`) as action view.

When the user presses the back button, the soft keyboard will hide. What I want is when the soft keyboard gets hidden, I want the action view to collapse as well.

In `SearchView`, we can achieve such thing by using `setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener` - [Auto Collapse ActionBar SearchView on Soft Keyboard close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629313/auto-collapse-actionbar-searchview-on-soft-keyboard-close)

However, `AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't have such method. How can I achieve the same thing, in `AutoCompleteTextView`?