# Android EditText Blinking Cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have only one `EditText` in my Activity and I want it to hide the blinking cursor once the input is done - either the focus is switched or user presses **Done** - in other words, as the input keyboard disappears. 
Here's the code for the `EditText`.

```
<EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:textColor="@color/theme2"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/editText"
                android:nextFocusLeft="@id/editText"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425932/detecting-when-user-has-dismissed-the-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To stop the cursor from blinking in an `EditText`, simply use this line:

```
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Like where he would call this method, in which part of this program...