# Android Soft Keyboard: "Done" on "Dismiss"

Tags: android, events, keyboard, event-handling, android-softkeyboard

I want to handle "dismiss soft keyboard" event in Android, and as far as I understood, the only solution to do this is to subclass `EditText` which I did according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32754122/2202101).

Here is my class:

```
public class EditTextCustom extends EditText {

    public EditTextCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EditTextCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onStateChanged(this, true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.d("Info", "Soft keyboard was hidden");
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onStateChanged(this, false);
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }

    KeyboardListener listener;

    public void setOnKeyboardListener(KeyboardListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface KeyboardListener {
        void onStateChanged(EditTextCustom keyboardEditText, boolean showing);
    }
}
```

I need this event(s) (`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`) to act as `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`, that is when user dismisses soft keyboard, it is interpreted by Android if it has pressed `"Done"` and the edits to the `EditText` were applied.

Best practice to implement this?

Answer (score -1):

```
mEtNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // do something, e.g. set your TextView here via .setText()
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

mEtNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // do something, e.g. set your TextView here via .setText()
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and in xml

android:imeOptions="actionDone"

This may help you.

Comment: And as far as I understood, this does things when "Done" is pushed. And I need an action when "Dismiss" is pushed.