# Android: Kotlin how to capture keyboard dismiss event

Tags: android

I have a MVVM application I am working on I have added some animations to a screen and I need to fire them off when the user hides the keyboard. I have overridden the onbackpress however that is not called when a keyboard is hidden.

[what I want to capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63yfN.png)

edit: keyboard is set to adjust nothing as I want the animation to move the screen and resize things. So looking at size doesn't work. I was initially using https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent but this doesn't work with adjust nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Soft keyboard open and close listener in an activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/soft-keyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android)

Comment: you can check [this](https://github.com/J-Jamet/keyboard-visibility-event-android) library for capturing keyboard events

Comment: @0X0nosugar I can't use the size to check. as I need the keyboard to adjust nothing.

Comment: @MohammedAlaa I am going to assume the library is doing a size check and I can't use those, I was already using one.

Comment: Then how about [overriding onKeyPreIme() for your EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425932/detecting-when-user-has-dismissed-the-soft-keyboard)?